# How can I verify if a string contains numbers in validator.js?

Tags: javascript, validation, express-validator

I want to validate to make sure a string doesn't contain number. i.e. *Name*

How can I use validatorjs to achieve this? (I would prefer **not to** use regex.)

```
    if (!validator.( ??? )) {
    throw new Error(
      "Name can only contain letter, please re-enter the name"
    );
  }
```

what should I add in `???` field?

Answer (score 0):

Try isAlpha function, you can look at all the functions here: [validatorjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator)

```
if (!validator.isAlpha(yourString)) {
  throw new Error(
    "Name can only contain letter, please re-enter the name"
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking some time to reply. I tried something else and it worked as well.

```if (!validator.isAlpha(validator.blacklist(name, " "))) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Name can only contain letters, please re-enter the name");
  }```